# Store Enums in DB

Tags: java, database, jpa

I was asked to make a a column called `Type` a `varchar2(1)`which has values `partial` or `all`

That what i made in **Model.Java**

```
    @Column(name="TYPE")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TypeEnum getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(TypeEnum type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
```

And this is my **TypeEnum.java**

```
public enum TypeEnum {
    ALL(0, "all"),
    PARTIAL(1, "partial");

    private int code;
    private String value;

    private TypeEnum(int code, String value) {
        this.code = code;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static TypeEnum getTypeEnum(String value){
        TypeEnum[] types = values();
        for(int i=0; i<types.length; i++){
            TypeEnum type = types[i];
            if(value.equals(type.getValue()))
                return type;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

So how to store the TypeEnum in DB to achieve the varchar2(1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Converter to map your enums to varchar(1) yourself.  Something like:

```
@Column("TYPE") @Convert(TypeEnumToString.class) TypeEnum type;
```

with the converter class implemented something like:

```
public class TypeEnumToString implements AttributeConverter<TypeEnum, String> {
  @Override
  public TypeEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
    // return conversion;
  }
  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(TypeEnum value) {
    // return conversion;               
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by implementing `AttributeConverter<TypeEnum, String>`

```
@Converter
public class TypeEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<TypeEnum, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(TypeEnum attribute) {
        return String.valueOf(attribute.getCode());
    }

    @Override
    public TypeEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return getTypeEnumFromCode(parseInt(dbData));
    }
}
```

`getTypeEnumFromCode` can be implemented similar to your `getTypeEnum` method.

Then, define it like

```
@Column("TYPE")
@Convert(TypeEnumToString.class)
TypeEnum type;
```

p.s.I just used `code` from your enum but it can be any other logic too.